# DeMorgan's law and C++

Tags: c++, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, demorgans-law

For each of the following write the equivalent C++ expressions, without any unary negation operators (!). (!= is still permitted)

Use DeMorgan's law

- `!( P && Q) = !P || !Q`
- `!( P || Q) = !P && !Q`

For

1. `!(x!=5 && x!=7)`
2. `!(x<5 || x>=7)`
3. `!( !(a>3 && b>4) && (c != 5))`

My answers:

1. `(x>5 || x<5) || (x>7 || x<7)`
2. `x>=5 && x < 7`
3. `(a>3 && b > 4) && (c!=5)`

Are these correct? If not, can you give me answers and explain why they are wrong?

I am a beginner in C++ so take it easy.

Comment: how did you new `>` and `<` opperators from demorgan's for 1?

Comment: Since I cant use ! (!= is permitted though), I had to use < and >.

Comment: I thought that the opposite of #1 is x is greater than or less than 5 or x is greater than 7 or less than 7.

Comment: Why not write some code and test your assumptions.

Comment: The opposite of `x!=5` is `x==5` for #1 you first apply Demorgan's first rule `!(x!=5 && x!=7)   ->   !(x!=5) || !(x!=7)` Then you know that `!(x!=5) -> x==5` and `!(x!=7) -> x==7` so you are left with `!(x!=5 && x!=7) -> x==5 || x==7`

Comment: Thank you everyone. I never knew the opposite of != was ==. I originally thought that the opposite was just "="

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
!(x!=5 && x!=7)                 -->    x==5 || x==7

!(x<5 || x>=7)                  -->    x>=5 && x<7

!( !(a>3 && b>4) && (c != 5))   -->    (a>3 && b>4) || c==5
```

So, just #2 from your solutions is correct.

Comment: Why did you use "==" instead? I thought "==" was used only for equality-testing. Isn't "!=" meant "not equal to"? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: `!(x != y)`  => `(x == y)`