# Appears that no further code executes after break from while loop (c++)

Tags: c++, while-loop, break

I'm learning c++ and creating a small rpg-esque game.

I've got a function to give initial stat points, however once all of the points are added I seem to be unable to break out of the while loop and execute the cout after the loop. Please note that all the skill names and CharacterName are forward declared and the names of skills are typed in full. RemainingPoints is also forward declared. All continues execute correctly. There are also no compiler errors.

```
void CharacterSkillSetup()
{
    std::string SelectedSkill;
    int AssignedPoints;

    while(SelectedSkill != "Muscle" || SelectedSkill != "Focus"
        || SelectedSkill != "Reflexes" || SelectedSkill != "Cogni"
        || SelectedSkill != "Precision" || SelectedSkill != "Resistance"
        || SelectedSkill != "Luck" || SelectedSkill != "Finished")

    {
        std::cout << "\nWell then " << CharacterName
            << ", you seem like you have the capacity for a bit of training. \n \n";
        std::cout << "You can train in the following skills: \n";
        std::cout << "Muscle " << MuscleSkill << " - Increase Physical and Ranged damage. \n";
        std::cout << "Focus " << FocusSkill << " - Increase Magical damage. \n";
        std::cout << "Reflexes " << ReflexesSkill << " - Increase Physical and Ranged speed. \n";
        std::cout << "Cogni " << CogniSkill << " - Increase Magical speed. \n";
        std::cout << "Precision " << PrecisionSkill << " - Increase hit chance. \n";
        std::cout << "Resistance " << ResistanceSkill
            << " - Increase hitpoints and lessen damage received. \n";
        std::cout << "Luck " << LuckSkill << " - Increase value of loot drops. \n \n";
        std::cout << "You currently have " << RemainingPoints << " skillpoints to assign. \n \n";
        std::cout <<
            "Please type the full name of the skill followed by how many points you wish \nto assign to it.\n";
        std::cout << "\nIf you wish to assign some skillpoints at a later time type 'Finished 0'\n";
        std::cin >> SelectedSkill >> AssignedPoints;
        if(std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
        }

        if(AssignedPoints > 14 || AssignedPoints < 0 || (RemainingPoints - AssignedPoints < 0))
        {
            AssignedPoints = 0;
        }

        if(SelectedSkill == "Muscle")
        {
            MuscleSkill = MuscleSkill + AssignedPoints;
            RemainingPoints = RemainingPoints - AssignedPoints;
        }

        else if(SelectedSkill == "Focus")
        {
            FocusSkill = AssignedPoints + FocusSkill;
            RemainingPoints = RemainingPoints - AssignedPoints;
        }

        else if(SelectedSkill == "Reflexes")
        {
            ReflexesSkill = AssignedPoints + ReflexesSkill;
            RemainingPoints = RemainingPoints - AssignedPoints;
        }

        else if(SelectedSkill == "Cogni")
        {
            CogniSkill = AssignedPoints + CogniSkill;
            RemainingPoints = RemainingPoints - AssignedPoints;
        }

        else if(SelectedSkill == "Precision")
        {
            PrecisionSkill = AssignedPoints + PrecisionSkill;
            RemainingPoints = RemainingPoints - AssignedPoints;
        }

        else if(SelectedSkill == "Resistance")
        {
            ResistanceSkill = AssignedPoints + ResistanceSkill;
            RemainingPoints = RemainingPoints - AssignedPoints;
        }

        else if(SelectedSkill == "Luck")
        {
            LuckSkill = AssignedPoints + LuckSkill;
            RemainingPoints = RemainingPoints - AssignedPoints;
        }

        else if(SelectedSkill == "Finished")
        {
            std::string Choice;

            std::cout << "Are you sure you're finished adding points? \n";
            std::cin >> Choice;

            if(Choice == "Yes")
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(Choice == "No")
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        if(RemainingPoints = 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Loop finished";
}
```

Comment: All you have to do is set `SelectedSkill` to one of those magic string, and your while loop will terminate, does that never happen at the `cin` line?

Comment: Read about DeMorgan's Law regarding your while statement.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949375/demorgans-law-and-c

Comment: @ChrisO the cin.fail() check and the cin.clear() which follows it ensures that SelectedSkill can't terminate the loop as a means to potentially stop abuse of the function, forcing the user to use Finished to leave points remainding. At least I think that's what you're talking about.

Comment: Oops, read up on the link from @KeithSmith, and also imagine what happens if the user enters `Luck` (case-sensitive compares BTW), so when `SelectedSkill == "Luck"`, look at the rest of the comparisons in the while condition, they'll evaluate to true, thus ensuring your infinite loop.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to break from the loop via RemainingPoints or Choice, I did try all of the above conditions in parentheses followed by && RemainingPoints != 0. So, while((previous conditions) && RemainingPoints != 0), however that had the same issue of no executing the cout

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to this particular break.  The if statement is an assignment of 0 to RemainingPoints and so will never evaluate to true.  You should use ==, a common typo.

```
    if(RemainingPoints = 0)
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the typo, however "loop finished" is still not executed. Whenever RemainingPoints == 0 after pressing enter for say Luck 14 (as RemainingPoints is assigned to 14 on initialisation) it'll allow me to keep typing and won't execute further code.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(RemainingPoints = 0)
{
   break;
}
```

That's why it's better to write

```
if(0 = RemainingPoints)
```

and have a compiler error instead of an annoying bug

Comment: Or better still, turn on the compiler warning that complains about such a scenario ;-)