# Merge-Sort on linked list

Tags: c++

Could anyone tell me the difference between these two code segments with and 
   without return statement?What will be the effect?

```
void mergeSort( struct Node** headRef )
{
   if( ( *headRef == nullptr  ||  (*headRef)->link == nullptr ) ) 
   {
      return
   }
      nodePtr leftPart ;
      nodePtr rightPart ;

      divideList( *headRef , &leftPart , &rightPart ) ;

      mergeSort( &leftPart ) ;
      mergeSort( &rightPart ) ; 

     *headRef = sortedMerge( leftPart , rightPart ) 
}


void mergeSort( struct Node** headRef )
{
   if( ( *headRef != nullptr  ||  (*headRef)->link != nullptr ) ) 
   {
      nodePtr leftPart ;
      nodePtr rightPart ;

      divideList( *headRef , &leftPart , &rightPart ) ;

      mergeSort( &leftPart ) ;
      mergeSort( &rightPart ) ; 

     *headRef = sortedMerge( leftPart , rightPart ) ;
   }
}
```

In the first segment i used return statement which will return me a node when its link is null but i'm trying to figure out if the same thing can happen with the second segment as first? –

Comment: That second one will give you real problems when `headRef` is null. And the last paragraph of you question is unintelligible.

Comment: In the first segment i used return statement which will return me a node when its link is null but i'm trying to figure out if the same thing can happen with the second segment as first?

Comment: As stated, the second one is *broken*. Consider what state would trigger evaluation of `(*headRef)->link != nullptr`. For that to be considered, `*headRef != nullptr` must be *false*. But if that is false, that means `*headRef` must be null, which means the second conditional invokes undefined behavior by dereferencing a null pointer. To answer your question, the former returns quickly if either the head node pointer, or link member of the node it points to, refer to null (a list of zero or one elements). The second is tragically broken, and shouldn't be used. *That* is the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 blocks of code not the same.
For them to be the same, the line of code in the 2nd block

```
if( ( *headRef != nullptr  ||  (*headRef)->link != nullptr ) )
```

should be

```
if( ( *headRef != nullptr  &&  (*headRef)->link != nullptr ) )
```

You want to look at De'Morgans Laws which will tell you how to turn

```
if (!(expression))
```

into

```
if (a_different_expression)
```

Basically all &&'s become ||'s, all ||'s become &&'s, all sub_expressions become !sub_expressions (or remove !), all relational expressions invert ( >= becomes < ).
See [DeMorgan's law and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949375/demorgans-law-and-c)

Comment: ouh thank you brother you solved my seems bigger but minor problem